# Unable to use tensorflow with python 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, python-import

I have a CPU only laptop. I'm trying to use tensorflow in python using pycharm. I installed Python 3.8 (64 bit) and installed tensorflow successfully using `pip`. However, when i try to import tensorflow into python, it gives me the attached error. I'm new to python and pycharm. I'm running WIndows 10 on my system. 
The error I get is:

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37461

You are trying to use TensorFlow  on python3.8 which I doubt is not possible as the tensorflow doesn't support latest py version.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749#issuecomment-573313402 check this out

Comment: What version your are using? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374#issuecomment-605381497

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Visual Studio 2015-2019 x86 and x64 from here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Then restart your python script and it should work.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749

Comment: that's not for python 3.8. For python 3.8 they have not launched tensorflow for that.